# How do I find out why Windows 8.1 Pro forgets a user account password?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, passwords, user-accounts

I have created a standard - non-admin - user account on my Windows 8.1 Pro 64 Bit computer for sharing purposes only. I never log into the computer using that account. I use it only so my scanner can write to certain shared directories. (I don't trust my scanner with my real password.)

Every few months, sometimes twice within a month - the account loses its password. The scanner issues a "bad password or user account" error. Then I have to log into the admin user and reset the password and everything works fine for a month or two. I use the scanner at least twice a week.

I tried looking in the Event Viewer (eventvwr.exe) but I don't know how to filter for user account related issues.

I've tried googling the question, but I have not been able to word the search query so it gives meaningful results.

Is there a password expiration policy for Windows 8.1 that I don't know about? What events in the Event Viewer would give me some information on why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you don't have a local policy or GPO enforcing a password expiration.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f040ff7e-6b96-4b22-9e87-bb1ede35c79e/windows-8-password-expiration?forum=w8itprogeneral

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in the Event Viewer you would be looking for Security Audits.

Answer (score 1):

Next time it happens, check two things:

1. Check if the standard user account is locked out.
2. Try manually logging in to your PC with that account.

You can also have a look at the Security section in the event log to see if any particular error was logged.

My hunch is that the problem is in the scanner than the Windows OS.

Comment: You're right, I haven't even considered that the fault might be with the scanner. It worked fine on a previous Windows 8 machine, but there I had used the Admin User.